# Alternative to Prompt attribute?

Tags: c#, botframework

I would like to prompt the user to enter a numeric value in a custom range:

```
 [Prompt("How much would you like to enter? {||}")]
    [Numeric(1, MaxValue)]
    public int Amount;
```

Not surprisingly I'm getting the following error, for `MaxValue`

> attribute argument must be constant expression.

Any ideas for a different approach with similar result?

Answer (score 1):

U store this as an Int so why not:

```
[Prompt("How much would you like to enter? {||}")]
[Numeric(1, int.MaxValue)]
public int Amount;
```

Comment: MaxValue is not int.MaxValue but an arbitrary value decided run-time.

Comment: I see now, If you want to use atributes u need to use const but you always can create it in runtime like:

 new NumericAttribute(1, MaxValue)

Comment: but that does not really solve the issue. I want to be able to PROVIDE maxValue at runtime. MaxValue is not known at compile-time. I don't think you can accomplish this using attributes. I guess the botframework provides a different mechanism for use in cases like this. This question is basically about such mechanisms